# Extract only numbers from a mixed alpha numeric string

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use regular expression to extract series of digits from a string that represents mixed alpha sentence.

Examples:

```
"Please buy 40 kg of apples for 1350$ each"                  --> "40|1350"
"Please call 8 0 0 4 3 2 1 2 4 3 from 17:00 till 22:00"      --> "8004321243|1700|2200"
"I would like to bid 50 euro on 20 black and pair of spades" --> "50|20"
```

So only digits extracts, and any word in between are truncated to `|` separator. If the digits are separated by a non-word character, they are considers as the same number as on the 2nd example.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all non-word chars with `Regex.Replace(s, @"\W+", "")`, and then extract all digit chunks with the simple `\d+` pattern:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(Regex.Replace(s, @"\W+", ""), @"\d+")
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(m=>m.Value)
       .ToList();
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ucB681).

Answer (score 0):

you could first try to search for digits followed by digits plus nonword chars and sanitize the regex matches afterwards:

```
var str = "Please call 8 0 0 4 3 2 1 2 4 3 from 17:00 till 22:00";

var regex1 = new Regex(@"([\d]+[\d\W]*)");
var regex2 = new Regex(@"([\W]+)");    

foreach (var match in regex1.Matches(str).Cast<Match>())
{
    var val = match.Groups[1].Value;    

    foreach (var nonWordMatch in regex2.Matches(val).Cast<Match>())
    {
        val = val.Replace(nonWordMatch.Value, "");
    }

    var number = Int64.Parse(val);
    Console.WriteLine(">> num " + number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
List<string> test = new List<string>();

foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c)) {
           number.append(c);
        }
        else if (c == ' ' || c == ':') {
          //donnothing
        }
        else {
           if (number.Length > 0) {
           test.add(number.ToString());
           number.Clear();
           }
        }
    }
```